# Inconsistent lxml.etree.xpath element counting between Mac OS and Linux hosts

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

This problem has puzzled me for a while now. I am trying to scrape tables from financial websites. For example, from barchart.com ( finviz.com same problem )

```
import lxml.html as lh
import lxml, urllib2

gList = ['gapup','gapdown']
count = {}
doc = {}
for g in gList:
    doc[g] = lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.barchart.com/stocks/{0}.php'.format(g)))
    count[g] = len(doc[g].xpath('/html/body//table[4]//tr'))
```

Basically, I am counting how many rows (stocks) there are in the table. On my macbook (Python 2.7.5+ lxml 3.2.4). Works perfect:

```
In [14]: count
Out[14]: {'gapdown': 101, 'gapup': 34}
```

However, when I test the same code remotely on my dreamhost site. Won't work:

```
In [7]: count
Out[7]: {'gapdown': 0, 'gapup': 0}
```

Initially, I thought it's because Python 2.6 on dreamhost, and 2.6 is known to have less xpath support. So I installed pyenv to use 2.7.5 today. Problem is still there.

I tried to get around using this code (I call it xpath relay :) ):

```
In [11]: len(doc['gapup'].xpath('/html/body//table')[3].xpath('//tr'))
Out[11]: 43
```

As the number suggests (43 != 34), didn't work. Using `lh.tostring()` , I realize it basically picked up all tr-s in the html file. No relay.

I am new to xpath. But why the same code won't work on same python 2.7 + lxml 3.2.4 setup on different machines? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try dumping the page. Is it the same? Probably they do not want to be scraped and block some hosting ip ranges.

Comment: @JensErat, I did dump the page using lh.tostring(). It's the same table on both machines with this code `doc['gapup'].xpath('/html/body//table')[3]`. The problem is child selection code `'/html/body//table[4]//tr'` won't work on the Debian machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue on an Ubuntu 12.04 host with Python 2.7.3.

For some reason, the table is the fifth table sometimes. Anyway, when parsing HTML documents, better do not rely on counting elements, but use `@id` attributes if given.

Using the XPath expression `//table[@id="dt1"]//tr` I could get reproducible results, also on my Ubuntu host.

Comment: Indeed! I tried your suggestion. Works like a charm. I just learned to use attributes in xpath a few hours ago. It is definitely more reliable than counting.

So, after all, there are some wired xpath counting bug with linux  host (Debian 6.06 Ubuntu 12.04) but not Mac OS X (10.9)